# Random access csv file content

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I'm looking at a way to access a csv file's cells in a random fashion. If I use Python's csv module, I can only iterate through all lines which is rather slow. I should also add that the file is pretty large (>100MB) and that I'm looking at short response time.

I could preprocess the file into a different data format for faster row/column access. Perhaps someone has done this before and can share some experiences.

Background:

I'd like to show an extract of the csv on screen provided by a web server (depending on scroll position). Keeping the file in memory is not an option.

Comment: If you don't want to iterate over a file (no matter in which format), maybe a file is not your first choice of persistence. If access time is an issue, have you thought about using a DB?

Comment: you can take a look at memory mapped files http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html

Comment: you can iterate over the file and keep an array of the cell locations, like pointers to the cell. These can then be used to seek to the specific location. This offcourse still depends on the IO speed. See my comment above for increasing that with a big memory buffer.

Comment: I would try Joram's answer about pointers. You can keep track only of pointers to lines if you process entire lines at a time. And if it fits your needs, you can even build an index on some key variables. I have already done that to do statistics on large (20 GB) files, and it saves time, but in my case, the intersting unit was the whole line.

Comment: What do you want to do with the file? only *read* it? then saving the rows obtained from the csv module in a list should be quite efficient. If you need to constantly *update* the CSV file and do this quickly, then the SQLite approach is more adapted.

Comment: @EOL: Reading is fine. No need to change the file. I might need to iterate through thousands of rows...

Comment: @Joram: See my update. You suggest some sort of index to directly access row/colums. I wonder which solution (sqlite or this) would be better (faster access/preprocessing, memory size, robustness)... I guess it'll be sqlite, especially since it doesn't require me to work out a structure of the index, but I asked to learn about other options.

Comment: @arbautjc: What was your sqlite:csv file size ratio (not that disk size matters much, but I'm curious).

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Indeed, that's what I'm trying to ascertain :-). I'm not biased towards a file solution, but would want to keep the effort at a minimum (note that sqlite is also a file solution).

Comment: @orange. I didn't use sqlite, only "raw" csv files and python hash tables for indexing (stored as is on disk between runs).

Comment: @orange At some point all DB boil down to file accesses if they are persistent, as your DBMS has to store the information somehwere. But the DBMS is already optimized and has decades of development invested into it.

Comment: @arbautjc: What did yo store in these hashtables and how did you store them to disk (did you pickle them)? You'd need to load the tables into memory in order to address the csv rows/columns...

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Absolutely. So whatever I come up with as solution may be a half-baked DBMS. I'm just trying to find out whether there is anything 'better' out there for this special use case.

Comment: @orange. The hash had for example "(var1, var2): [list of row indices]", and I store it with f.write(str(hash)), but I guess pickle would be better. When reading csv file to do cross tables with filters, I store first the variable names (first row), and I build a hash: h[name]=column, to get later variables by names. If I have a filter on an indexed variable, I use the indexed rows, otherwise I read everything row by row, using split("\t") (it's actually usually tab-separated, since I have sometimes a variable that can hold a string with commas).

Comment: A cross-tabulation is also done by hashes: I store for each crossing a hash (var1 ... varn): f(var), where f(var) is usually the sum of population weight. In the end, crossings are stored as html tables, that can be read by Excel (I may use COM now, but I had little knowledge of it then). All in all, it's not very fast, but not much slower than SAS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found SQLite good for this sort of thing. It is easy to set up and you can store the data locally, but you also get easier control over what you select than csv files and you get the facility to add indexes etc.

There is also a built in facility for loading csv files into a table: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles.

Let me know if you want any further details on the SQLite route i.e. how to create the table, load the data in or query it from Python.

**SQLite Instructions to load .csv file to table**

To create a database file you can just add the filename required as an argument when opening SQLite. Navigate to the directory containing the csv file from the command line (I am assuming here that you want the SQLite .db file to be contained in the same dir). If using Windows add SQLite to your PATH environment variable if not already done, (instructions [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) if you need them) and open SQLite as follows with an argument for the name that you want to give your database file e.g.:

```
sqlite3 example.db
```

Check the database file has been created by entering:

```
.databases
```

Create a table to hold the data. I am using an example for a simple customer table here. If data types are inconsistent for any columns use text:

```
create table customers (ID integer, Title text, Forename text, Surname text, Postcode text, Addr_Line1 text, Addr_Line2 text, Town text, County text, Home_Phone text, Mobile text, Comments text);
```

Specify the separator to be used:

```
.separator ","
```

Issue the command to import the data, the sytnax takes the form `.import filename.ext table_name` e.g.:

```
.import cust.csv customers
```

Check that the data has loaded in:

```
select count(*) from customers;
```

Add an index for columns that you are likely to filter on (full syntax described [here](http://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)) e.g.:

```
create index cust_surname on customers(surname);
```

You should now have fast access to the data when filtering on any of the indexed columns. To leave SQLite use `.exit`, to get a list of other helpful non-SQL commands use `.help`.

**Python Alternative**

Alternatively if you want to stick with pure Python and pre-process the file then you could load the data into a dictionary which would allow much faster access to the data as the dictionary keys behave like an index meaning that you can get to values associated with a key quickly without going through the records one by one. I would need further details of your input data and what fields the lookups would be based on to provide further details on how to implement this.

However, unless you will know in advance when the data will be required (to be able to pre-process the file before the request for data) then you would still have the overhead of loading the file from disk into memory every time you run this. Depending on your exact usage this may make the database solution more appropriate.

Comment: I thought the database solution would be a bit too much, but come to think about it, it may be a suitable solution. What's the disk overhead and what table structure would you choose. Is there an easy way to load the file from Python? A dict wouldn't work as I can't load the whole file in memory.

Comment: If you mean how much room does the SQLite program take up on disk it's pretty small. The executable is ~0.5 MB and, (the source code is ~5 MB, but you don't need to keep this). In terms if the data structure I would need to know more about your data to be able to advise. Can you post some sample lines in the question?

Comment: Sqlite is already part of Python std libs (IMHO). What I was meant to ask was what the sqlite database file size would be compared to the csv file. As for the csv records, the columns are unlabelled (it's not defined what type or meaning they have). Would you store them with a row/column primary key together with a string value?

Comment: @orange I have updated the answer above with some instructions and an example of importing a .csv file to SQLite. Let me know if any of this needs further explanation. To answer your question about file overhead, the .db file created by SQLite took around 10% more space than the csv file in my example (a 15MB csv file), this will probably vary depending on the data, but the overhead should not be too significant.

Comment: I'll probably end up doing the import in Python and write it to a sqlite db. Holding all this data in a dict is not a viable option for me, as it could be quite large.